# Adjusting Cart Order (allowing custom QTY)

Tags: php, jquery, hash, shopping-cart

Currently using a Food Delivery script that is actually awesome and fills out all the basic requirements I was looking for! However a small issue is that when you add something to your cart, if you want to adjust the quantity, you have to click a - or + sign. How can I remove that and replace it with a box that allows the user to insert their own number instead of slowly clicking the + sign.

Below is the code for the cart section.

```
<td>
<a href="#" class="fdCartAdjust" data-hash="<?php echo $hash; ?>" 
data-direction="down">-</a> <?php echo $item['cnt']; ?> <a href="#" 
class="fdCartAdjust" data-hash="<?php echo $hash; ?>" data-direction="up">+</a>
</td>
```

[image: Also here is an image of the cart where the - + shows.]

Additional CSS code related to this section of the cart -

```
.fdCartAdjust{
text-decoration: none;
}
```

Any help will be amazing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In whole (as the mention from OpenCart long term programmer), it is a bit tricky task. It is not a hard, but a tricky.

Those adjustments done with JS+jQuery. When you click on the link with the class `fdCartAdjust`, some event will be triggered, which will send AJAX request to your 'shopping-cart' which will add or remove (depends on 'data-direction' attribute) one unit of product.

You need find in JS-code some part kind of:

```
$('.fdCartAdjust').on('click', function(){
    //blahblah
});
```

Or:

```
$('.fdCartAdjust').click(function(){
        //blahblah
});
```

Or something similar. Look at this code an determine what the address is used for sending the request. E.g. `index.php?route=product/cart/add`.

Depending on this address you need to determine PHP code, which is responsible for adding/deleting units to the cart.

Since you've determined this, you can modify this code or add new which will serve the situation when you need update cart with new volume, instead of just add/remove one unit.

After adding the PHP code, replace `<?php echo $item['cnt']; ?>` to the `<input type="text" value="<?php echo $item['cnt']; ?>" class="fdCartChange">` and add in your JS something like:

```
$('.fdCartChange').on('change', function(){
    //code which will send request to PHP code you added.
});
```

It is complex task. In whole, you need understand the structure of your current 'shopping-cart' engine for making those 'little' adjustments. From the code you published I even can't see what the engine you've used, so I've published approximate plan for OpenCart. For other engines this algorithm may be different.

Comment: Oh wow awesome explanation thank you. Looks like a lot of guess and checking will be required til I find out what the go is.  

    `}).delegate(".fdCartAdjust", "click", function (e) {
    if (e && e.preventDefault) {
     e.preventDefault();
    }
    var $this = pjQ.$(this);
    self.adjustCart.apply(self, [$this.data("hash"), $this.data("direction")]);`  
  
    That's the code I found in the main FoodDelivery.js file. Only file on the whole server that refers to fdCartAdjust (other then the CSS file etc)